# Figure out which properties accessed on expando object

Tags: c#, dictionary, dynamic, expandoobject

I use a template engine that renders templates from c# objects (nested).  I would like to reflect and figure out which properties / objects are used in each template string.

An ideal way would be to build a "dummy" object representing the right shape and render this in the template.  I would then inspect this object afterwards to find out which properties were accessed.  This would allow me to keep this logic independant of the template library.

Any idea how i might implement this?  The expando object is built dynamically like this:

```
var dynamicObject = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;
foreach (var property in properties) {
    dynamicObject.Add(property.Key,property.Value);
}
```

Had some ideas along these lines:

```
public class DummyObject {

    public DummyObject() {
        Accessed = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
    }
    public Dictionary<string, bool> Accessed;

    object MyProp {
        get {
            Accessed["MyProp"] = true;
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

But this custom property obviously doesn't work with the dictionary / expando object.  Any ideas of a route forward here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the [`TryGetMember`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.trygetmember(v=vs.110).aspx) method on [`DynamicObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public sealed class LoggedPropertyAccess : DynamicObject {
    public readonly HashSet<string> accessedPropertyNames = new HashSet<string>();
    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result) {
        accessedPropertyNames.Add(binder.Name);
        result = "";
        return true;
    }
}
```

and then the following will output the accessed property names

```
dynamic testObject = new LoggedPropertyAccess();
string firstname = testObject.FirstName;
string lastname = testObject.LastName;
foreach (var propertyName in testObject.accessedPropertyNames) {
    Console.WriteLine(propertyName);
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

---

N.B. There is still an issue here -- this works only as long as the template library expects only `string`s from the properties. The following code will fail, because every property will return a string:

```
DateTime dob = testObject.DOB;
```

In order to resolve this, and also allow for nested objects, have `TryGetMember` return a new instance of `LoggedPropertyAccess`. Then, you can override the [`TryConvert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.tryconvert(v=vs.110).aspx) method as well; where you can return different values based on the conversion to different types (complete code):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Dynamic;

namespace DynamicObjectGetterOverride {
    public sealed class LoggedPropertyAccess : DynamicObject {
        public readonly Dictionary<string, object> __Properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        public readonly HashSet<string> __AccessedProperties = new HashSet<string>();

        public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result) {
            if (!__Properties.TryGetValue(binder.Name, out result)) {
                var ret = new LoggedPropertyAccess();
                __Properties[binder.Name] = ret;
                result = ret;
            }
            __AccessedProperties.Add(binder.Name);
            return true;
        }

        //this allows for setting values which aren't instances of LoggedPropertyAccess
        public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value) {
            __Properties[binder.Name] = value;
            return true;
        }

        private static Dictionary<Type, Func<object>> typeActions = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object>>() {
            {typeof(string), () => "dummy string" },
            {typeof(int), () => 42 },
            {typeof(DateTime), () => DateTime.Today }
        };

        public override bool TryConvert(ConvertBinder binder, out object result) {
            if (typeActions.TryGetValue(binder.Type, out var action)) {
                result = action();
                return true;
            }
            return base.TryConvert(binder, out result);
        }
    }
}
```

and use as follows:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;

namespace DynamicObjectGetterOverride {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            dynamic testObject = new LoggedPropertyAccess();
            DateTime dob = testObject.DOB;
            string firstname = testObject.FirstName;
            string lastname = testObject.LastName;

            dynamic address = testObject.Address;
            address.House = "123";
            address.Street = "AnyStreet";
            address.City = "Anytown";
            address.State = "ST";
            address.Country = "USA";

            WriteLine("----- Writes the returned values from reading the properties");
            WriteLine(new { firstname, lastname, dob });
            WriteLine();

            WriteLine("----- Writes the actual values of each property");
            foreach (var kvp in testObject.__Properties) {
                WriteLine($"{kvp.Key} = {kvp.Value}");
            }
            WriteLine();

            WriteLine("----- Writes the actual values of a nested object");
            foreach (var kvp in testObject.Address.__Properties) {
                WriteLine($"{kvp.Key} = {kvp.Value}");
            }
            WriteLine();

            WriteLine("----- Writes the names of the accessed properties");
            foreach (var propertyName in testObject.__AccessedProperties) {
                WriteLine(propertyName);
            }
            ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked a treat for the top level.  Going to give the nesting a try like you suggest

Comment: @PaulGrimshaw I've updated my answer to allow for nested objects, and also to allow for returning to different types via `TryConvert`.